# Flagging question as "off-topic" crashes the app

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, ios-app

As the title suggests, when choosing to flag a question as "this question should be closed for another reason" -> "off topic", the application crashes.

I have tried multiple questions on both Stack Overflow and Meta, and observed this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a crash related to some of the markdown that exists in the flags, as you also reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225329/flagging-options-include-raw-markdown)

This should be fixed in the next version,  0.1.26.