# Flagging options include raw-markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, ios-app

When flagging a post, any options which include markdown show the markdown raw, without stripping/ obeying to it.

For example, on meta, the "close for another reason" -> "off topic" includes markdown for a link:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the report, I'm working to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. You should no longer see the markdown as of version 0.1.26.