# Crash when trying to migrate question

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, migration, ios-app

iOS App, version 1.0.1.

Edit → Close → Off topic because… → Belongs on another site…

Crash!

I'm a moderator on the site — maybe that's a contributing factor.  It is 100% reproducible on all questions I have tried on both the main site and meta site.

This bug is distinct from [Flagging question as "off-topic" crashes the app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225328/148099).

Comment: Can't repro on Stack Overflow so most likely it's due to your diamond indeed, or maybe because the site is in beta.

Comment: The fix for the [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225328/flagging-question-as-off-topic-crashes-the-app) you mention hasn't been deployed. From a behavior point of view they are the same bug.